# Print file path from repository root - Rust logger

Tags: logging, rust

I am trying to figure out how to print file path from repository root.

https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/ - example here only talks about `record.file()` which prints absolute file path.

Is there a native way to print it from repository root (and not from the modules' Cargo.toml path).

My project is organized like:

```
root
|- module_A
           |- Cargo.toml
           |- src/<rest of code> 
|- module_B
           |- Cargo.toml
           |- src/<rest of code>
```

So, while logging, I'd to print the path as: `root/module_A/src/<file_path>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While cargo has packages and [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html) that cover more of the codebase, the compiler is only concerned with individual crates. So any notion of a source file (as you would from the `file!()` macro which env-logger uses) will be relative to the *crate* root.

There is no way (as far as I know) to modify that.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your binaries, they can be deployed independently from each other. In prod you will simply put them in certain directories, there won't be a notion of "repository root" or "repository". So I don't think it would really make sense for the logger to "natively" support such thing.